# using ajax to get data from a database with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have this code in asp.net and want to know how can it modify it to use in php
---------------------------------------------asp.net---------------------------------------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // calling jquery functions once document is ready
       $(document).ready(function () {
        // retreving data on button click
        $("#btnLoad").click(LoadDataThroughAjaxCall);
        //loading screen functionality - this part is additional - start
        $("#divTable").ajaxStart(OnAjaxStart);
        $("#divTable").ajaxError(OnAjaxError);
        $("#divTable").ajaxSuccess(OnAjaxSuccess);
        $("#divTable").ajaxStop(OnAjaxStop);
        $("#divTable").ajaxComplete(OnAjaxComplete);
        //loading screen functionality - this part is additional - end
    });
    // ajax call
    function LoadDataThroughAjaxCall() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetShipDetails",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: OnFailure,
            error: OnError
        });
        // this avoids page refresh on button click
        return false;
    }
    // on sucess get the xml
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        //debugger;
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        var tweets = xml.find("Table");
        showOnATable(tweets);
    }
    // show data on a table
    function showOnATable(tweets) {
        //debugger;
        var headers = [];
        var rows = [];
        // header section
        headers.push("<tr>");
        headers.push("<td><b>tweets</b></td>");
        headers.push("<td><b>created</b></td>");
        headers.push("<td><b>source</b></td>");

        headers.push("</tr>");
        // rows section
        $.each(tweets, function () {
            var tweets = $(this);
            rows.push("<tr>");
            rows.push("<td>" + $(this).find("tweet_text").text() + "</td>");
            rows.push("<td>" + $(this).find("created_at").text() + "</td>");
            rows.push("<td>" + $(this).find("source").text() + "</td>");
            rows.push("</tr>");
        });
        var top = "<table class='gridtable'>";
        var bottom = "</table>";
        var table = top + headers.join("") + rows.join("") + bottom;
        $("#divTable").empty();
        $("#divTable").html(table);
    }
    // loading screen functionality functions - this part is additional - start
    function OnAjaxStart() {
        //debugger;
        //alert('Starting...');
        $("#divLoading").css("display", "block");
    }
    function OnFailure(response) {
        //debugger;
        alert('Failure!!!' + '<br/>' + response.reponseText);
    }
    function OnError(response) {
        //debugger;
        var errorText = response.responseText;
        alert('Error!!!' + '\n\n' + errorText);
    }
    function OnAjaxError() {
        //debugger;
        alert('Error!!!');
    }
    function OnAjaxSuccess() {
        //debugger;
        //alert('Sucess!!!');
        $("#divLoading").css("display", "none");
    }
    function OnAjaxStop() {
        //debugger;
        //alert('Stop!!!');
        $("#divLoading").css("display", "none");
    }
    function OnAjaxComplete() {
        //debugger;
        //alert('Completed!!!');
        $("#divLoading").css("display", "none");
    }
    // loading screen functionality functions - this part is additional - end
</script>
```

---------------------------------------my current php files---------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------js file--------------------------------------

```
('input#data-submit').on('click',function(){
     var data=$('input#data').val();
      var data2=$('select#data2').val();

      if(data2=="Name")
      {
          if($.trim(data)!=''){
              $.post('Ajax/dataloader.php',{data:data},function(data){
                $('div#load').text(data)
              });
          }
      }
      else if(data2=="Location")
      {
        if($.trim(data)!=''){
              $.post('Ajax/dataloader2.php',{data:data},function(data){
                $('div#load').text(data)
              });
          }
      }
```

---------------------------------------------php file-------------------------------------------------

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])==true&&empty($_POST['data'])==false){
            require_once('../connection.php');
            function clean($str)
            {
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
            {
                $str= stripslashes($str);
            }
            return str_replace("'", "''", $str);
            }

        //Sanitize the POST values
        $username = clean($_POST['data']);
            $result=sqlsrv_query($conn,"execute sp_ORDER_BY_name '$username'");
            if($result) {
            if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                     echo $row['name'].", ".$row['location'].", ".$row['tweet_text'].", ".$row['hashtags'].", ".$row['source']."<br />";

                    }
            }else {
                //Login failed
                 echo 'Name not found';

                }
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What don't you understand? Are you asking how to change your URL to point to a PHP page?

Comment: yes that and how to pass the data to the php page.